# Stop Javascript from rounding big numerical IDs

Tags: javascript

The following throws up an alert box reading: `211466719468855300`. Why is this happening, even when I try casting it to a String? How can I read it accurately?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="delete-link" data-id="211466719468855298">Delete</a>​
```

**JS:**

```
$('.delete-link').click(function(e) {
        var $item =$(this);
        var itemID = String($item.data('id'));
        alert(itemID);
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zUbym/1/

​

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's happening for two reasons:

1. jQuery does you the favor of converting your "data-" attribute values to "appropriate" types
2. Numbers that large cannot be represented exactly in JavaScript, because all numbers are 64-bit IEEE 794 floating point values.

If you get the attribute value with ".attr()" directly, you can avoid the numeric conversion, but you'll have to keep it a string. Alternatively, you could prefix your data values with some non-digit character ("_" or whatever) to keep jQuery from trying to do you a favor.

Comment: Pointy- That's some insidious behavior- thanks for the workarounds

Comment: @RoyiNamir well it's handy when your "data-" attributes look like JSON, but I agree it's a questionable feature.

Comment: Also note that this is specifically about "data-" attributes; ".attr()" won't do this for other element attributes, and ".prop()" won't do it either.